# Parsing attributes with namespaces with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to parse the XML provided by the U.S. Treasury on their website [here](http://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData?$filter=year(NEW_DATE)%20eq%202016) using LINQ's `XDocument`, and I am running into issues when trying to parse out the namespaces programatically.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData?$filter=year(NEW_DATE)%20eq%202016");
```

Here is a stripped-down version of their XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <entry>
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-01-04T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.61</d:BC_1YEAR>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

If I hard-code the namespaces to access the m:* and d:* elements to the values as they're defined in the root like so:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
XNamespace m = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata";
XNamespace d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";
```

then I can parse out the value of a date with

```
Convert.ToDateTime(doc.Root.Element(ns + "entry").Element(ns + "content").Element(m + "properties").Element(d + "NEW_DATE"));
```

and it works fine.  But I would rather not hard-code the namespaces, so I am trying to pull them out of the root using a similar method but I get `null` values back:

```
XNamespace ns = doc.Root.Attribute("xmlns").Value;   // gives "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
XNamespace m = doc.Root.Attribute(ns + "m").Value;   <--- ERROR because the attribute is null
XNamespace d = doc.Root.Attribute(ns + "d").Value;   <--- ERROR because the attribute is null
```

It turns out if I inspect the `d` and `m` attributes, they use the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/`, which must be the default. Why don't they use the namespace defined in the `xmlns` attribute like the elements do?  Does the order of the attributes matter?  Or maybe the `xmlns` namespace simply can't be overridden when used explicitly?

Comment: `xmlns` prefix is fixed for `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/` namespace and can not be overridden.

Comment: Would appear to be the case - I just tried a local version with the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"` appearing first and it still had the same issue, so order didn't matter. As long as I don't get burned hard-coding the xmlns then I should be fine. Just seems a little odd to me that it changes the namespace for the elements, but not the namespace tag itself - I feel like I'm looking at this from slightly the wrong angle.

Comment: I'd've thought hard coding the namespaces is far preferable to hard coding the prefixes. The prefixes can be changed and the XML is semantically the same - this is a lot more likely than the namespaces changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the attribute is `xmlns:d`. `xmlns` is reserved by the XML Namespaces standard. Any attribute or element starting with `xml` or `XML` is reserved by the XML standard. The attribute `xmlns` specifies the default namespace for the element or document.

```
 XNamespace d = doc.Root.Attribute(XNamespace.Xmlns+"d").Value;
 XNamespace m = doc.Root.Attribute(XNamespace.Xmlns+"m").Value;
```

Comment: Right, this is what I've ended up doing. Thanks. I particularly feel better after seeing the `XNamespace.Xmlns` property since it feels less like I'll have the rug pulled out later.